# Xcode iOS understanding the stack-trace

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, stack-trace

Is there something wrong with the applicationWillTerminate?

Who can tell me how to analysis the trace or more detail about the exception?

I tried dwarfdump but it seems no more detail.

```
dwarfdump -arch armv7 MyApp.app.dSYM --lookup 0x000034b3
```

tell me

```
Line table file: 'main.m' line 14, column 18 with start address 0x00000000000034aa
```

which is

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Here is the stack-trace

```
-[UIApplication applicationWillTerminate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x27eed0
(null)
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x30df964f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34914c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
2   CoreFoundation                      0x30dfd1bf -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
3   CoreFoundation                      0x30dfc649 ___forwarding___ + 508
4   CoreFoundation                      0x30d73180 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5   CommonTools                         0x089e441f -[ButtonEventOpt onProcClickEvent:state:frame:viewControl:] + 1662
6   CommonTools                         0x089ead37 -[CommonToolsView onClickBtnEvent:] + 366
7   CoreFoundation                      0x30d69571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
8   UIKit                               0x30e77ec9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 84
9   UIKit                               0x30e77e69 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 32
10  UIKit                               0x30e77e3b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
11  UIKit                               0x30e77b8d -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 356
12  UIKit                               0x30e78423 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 342
13  UIKit                               0x30e5d535 _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 2200
14  UIKit                               0x30e5cc01 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 696
15  CoreFoundation                      0x30dd0a35 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
16  CoreFoundation                      0x30dd2465 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
17  CoreFoundation                      0x30dd375b __CFRunLoopRun + 854
18  CoreFoundation                      0x30d63ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
19  CoreFoundation                      0x30d63dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
20  GraphicsServices                    0x306e241f GSEventRunModal + 114
21  GraphicsServices                    0x306e24cb GSEventRun + 62
22  UIKit                               0x30e89d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
23  UIKit                               0x30e87807 UIApplicationMain + 670
24  MyApp                           0x000034b3 MyApp + 9395
25  MyApp                           0x0000346c MyApp + 9324
)
```

Comment: Try dwarfdump on the addresses of ButtonEventOpt and CommonToolsView.

Comment: And are you sure there's not another "unrecognized selector" message, with more info in it?

Comment: dwarfdump -arch armv7 MyApp.app.dSYM --lookup 0x089ead37
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 File: MyApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyApp (armv7)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking up address: 0x00000000089ead37 in .debug_info... not found.
Looking up address: 0x00000000089ead37 in .debug_frame... not found.

Answer (score 0):

there are no errors in ApplicationWillTerminate, the application usually ends here when you get an unresolved error.

you should have got some details in the output log, your main error seems to be that you've called a selector which is not supported by the class on which you called:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x27eed0
```

in the stack you can see that there are several calls made, but only two of them are from your own classes (i guess, because i don't know these ones):

```
5   CommonTools                         0x089e441f -[ButtonEventOpt onProcClickEvent:state:frame:viewControl:] + 1662 
6   CommonTools                         0x089ead37 -[CommonToolsView onClickBtnEvent:] + 366
```

check your output log, if there are more details about your method call which is throwing the error.

Comment: If CommonTools is not your code then there's apparently none of your code in the stack, and the error you're seeing is due to handling an event you somehow previously scheduled to be handled.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know whether the CommonTools is my code. Is "CommonTools" a framework's name? I included a .a file and I doubt that's the position the code belong, but how could I check the functions or classes in the .a file?

Answer (score 0):

When is the application crashing? Looks like you are calling a method on an object that doesnt know about the method.

Please post the gesture recognizer code associated.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, I found it!
CommonTools is the library of 91桌面, a jailbreak app. When the user install this app, they can kill the app with it directly. My app get an crash report on os 4.x, when they quit the app using this app. So you can check if your app have the same problem. 
Good luck!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with stacktraces?

Comment: Yes it does. The crash is caused by the `CommonTools` framework, a jailbreak library that seems to hook itself into other apps.